# how to locate something mentioned in YAML?

Tags: css, r, yaml

Pardon the lack of reproducible data but here is the YAML in my R markdown file. When I run this on my machine, there is no problem. When someone else attempts it.. they get an error about the Nevada.png being missing. On my machine, I run the script and then in the console enter the following command (below). When I do so it says C://Users/myname/Documents. I would assume that this is where I will find the nevada.png item but it is not to be found.  Any tips on what you would do to find this .png item on your machine?

```
 getwd() 



title: Labor Market Briefing
subtitle: <span style="font-size:22px; font-family:'Arial'; color:#0A0A0A;3 font- 
weight:normal">April 2022</span><br></br>
author: <span style="font-size:18px; font-family:'Arial'; color:#0A0A0A; float:left; font- 
weight:normal">Analysis Bureau</span>
date: <span style="font-size:18px; font-family:'Arial'; color:#0A0A0A;font-style:normal; 
float:left">5/25/2021</span>
output: 
ioslides_presentation:
css: styles.css
logo: nevada.png
```

Comment: Make sure `nevada.png` is in the same directory as the Rmd document on whatever computer is compiling it.